# Can not complete deployment from of a community site from one sandbox to anther due to error parsing file

Tags: community, change-set, digital-experience

When we do a deployment of a Digital Experience site from one sandbox to another, using changesets, we get an error during the validation process that states:
Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}allowGuestPaymentsApi invalid at this location in type CustomSite

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that's a field added by having some B2C feature enabled somewhere. It's not a field listed in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sites.htm). Have you got something enabled on the source org that isn't enabled in the destination org?

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the comment, man! Its an org that multiple people work on so my suspicion is that someone likely added something for Commerce Cloud onto the Site which is why that API is visible.  I simply used workbench to export the XML for the change set and removed that line of code.  I then deployed it back to the org using change set and I am about to test it out but it should work fine.  Thanks again.